# Can't connect Linux box directly to ISP (through modem)

Tags: linux, networking, routing, isp

I have a Cisco EPC2202 modem given to me from my ISP. The modem connects to a TPLink router through an Ethernet Cat 5e cable. My desktop computer which is running CentOS 7 is connected to the TPLink router through an Ethernet Cat 5e cable.

I wanted to try an experiment and connect my CentOS computer directly to the modem, without using the TPLink router.

When I connect my computer directly to the modem using an Ethernet Cat 5e cable, NetworkManager (which is running dhclient for my ethernet interface) isn't able to give my interface an IP address. So, I decided to try manually. I saw the IP address, subnet mask and default gateway my TPLink router is receiving from my ISP through the web interface of the TPLink router. I configured the exact same settings on my Ethernet interface on my CentOS computer. I am still not able to `ping 8.8.8.8`. Traceroute packets aren't going out either.

Commands I used to configure my Ethernet (enp4s0f2) interface on my CentOS computer:

```
service NetworkManager stop

ip addr flush dev enp4s0f2

ip address add |My_public_IP_Address|/|Subnet_mask| dev enp4s0f2 broadcast +

ip route add to unicast 0.0.0.0/0 via |Default_gateway_IP_address_of_my_TPLink_router|
```

The commands pass without giving any errors and `ip addr show` and `ip route show` confirm that. Maybe they are using some VLAN configuration or PPP over Ethernet or something that my CentOS box doesn't understand?

Comment: A lot of this depends on the ISP. In the UK you can't even swap one ISP router for an identical model - it takes a phone call to enable it, even if it's an ISP engineer doing the swap.

Answer (score 2):

How is/was the TPLink router configured? If via DHCP, then you can do the same on your Linux box.  Note that some "modems" and/or service providers remember the MAC address plugged in and need to be rebooted in order to see and service a new MAC.  Although I've mostly seen this with cable modems.

If the TPLink wasn't configured via DHCP, then you probably need to set up PPPoE.  Been a long time since I've done it, but the Roaring Penguin PPoE client works/worked well for me.

Comment: My TPLink router is configured via DHCP, but network manager (which is running dhclient) on my CentOS box isn't able to acquire an ip address from my ISP. I think I'll spoof my MAC address (to be the same as my router) and run tcpdump to see what's happening. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Before you spoof, power cycle the modem - it may be holding on to the MAC address from the TPLink.

Comment: Hey I just wanted to inform you that yes the check seems to be MAC based (I guess the modem learns the mac address of the connected routing device after each power on). I plugged the modem into my CentOS computer and again it couldn't connect to the ISP. I disabled IPv6 on my computer and then powered off -> powered on the modem and after some time it configured an IP address on my interface and I had internet connectivity.